# $_xlnm#_filterdatabase files excel to sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, excel

When I'm trying to import an excel file to SQL Server, I see another table(s) with $_xlnm#_filterdatabase.
For instance if I have

> A.xlsx

as a one-sheet excel file, and I want to import it into SQL Server using SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data, I see another table as

> A$_xlnm#_filterdatabase

and for each sheet I see similar issue, except some sheets. I checked if filter is on or not. I removed all filters, but same is happening.

PS I also saw that some times the very same file, act normal without any $_xlnm#_filterdatabase files.

Could you please help me with it?
I also checked:

[multi-sheet import with oledb netting "_xlnm#_FilterDatabase" as sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034296/multi-sheet-import-with-oledb-netting-xlnm-filterdatabase-as-sheet-names)

But! I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have hidden sheets in Excel files?

Comment: Nope. I read somewhere that it is an autofilter, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is just ignore or drop down those sheets.
These are sheets that are not meant to be viewed by the user.

Just filter them out using this code.

```
if (!dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().Contains("_") && !dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
   {
   }
```

Use .Contains() and/or EndsWith to filter them out.